# Global Variable Not Assigning between Functions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, variables, global

I am writing an extension for Google Chrome in HTML/Javascript. I am trying to use a global variable to pass information between two functions, however even if I assign my variable in one function it hasn't changed when I read it from the other function.

```
    var type = 0; //define global variable
    window.onload=function(){onCreated()}; //set onCreated function to run after loading HTML

    function onCreated()
    {
        chrome.history.search({'text': ''},function(historyItems){gotHistory(historyItems)});//search for historyItems and then pass them to the gotHistory function
    }

    function gotHistory(historyItems)
    {
        var idcount=0;//used to increment the ids of each new element added
        for(var count=0; count < historyItems.length; count++)//go through each history item
        {
            chrome.history.getVisits({'url':historyItems[count].url}, function(visitItems){gotVisits(visitItems)}); //search for visitItems for the url and pass the results to gotVisists function (atm all this function does is assign the global variable to =3)

            var body = document.getElementById("outputid");//find the body of the HTML
            var newt = document.createElement("p");//create a new element
            newt.setAttribute("id","url"+idcount);//give it a unique id

            newt.innerHTML = historyItems[count].title;//set the text to say the title of the url

            if(type != 0)//if the other function was successful, type=3 and the text should be green
            {
                newt.style.color="green";
            }   

            body.appendChild(newt);//add the new element to the body
            idcount++;

        }
    }
    function gotVisits(visitItems)
    {
//assign the global variable to be 3
        type = 3;
    }
```

But, the elements are NEVER green. They should always be green. This means that in the function gotVisits, type is not being successfully assigned to 3.
Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Cheers,

Matt
p.s I realise the gotVisits function is useless here really, but I'm using it to demonstrate a point. In reality I will use it to pass back useful information to

Comment: When is gotVisits being called?

Comment: Near the start of got History: chrome.history.getVisits({'url':historyItems[count].url}, function(visitItems){gotVisits(visitItems)});

Answer (score 0):

Rather than:

```
var type = 0;
```

Try:

```
window.type = 0;
```

Optionally you can also use a closure such as:

```
(function() {

var type = 0;

    var type = 0; //define global variable
    window.onload=function(){onCreated()}; //set onCreated function to run after loading HTML

    function onCreated()
    {
        chrome.history.search({'text': ''},function(historyItems){gotHistory(historyItems)});//search for historyItems and then pass them to the gotHistory function
    }

    function gotHistory(historyItems)
    {
        var idcount=0;//used to increment the ids of each new element added
        for(var count=0; count < historyItems.length; count++)//go through each history item
        {
            chrome.history.getVisits({'url':historyItems[count].url}, function(visitItems){gotVisits(visitItems)}); //search for visitItems for the url and pass the results to gotVisists function (atm all this function does is assign the global variable to =3)

            var body = document.getElementById("outputid");//find the body of the HTML
            var newt = document.createElement("p");//create a new element
            newt.setAttribute("id","url"+idcount);//give it a unique id

            newt.innerHTML = historyItems[count].title;//set the text to say the title of the url

            if(type != 0)//if the other function was successful, type=3 and the text should be green
            {
                newt.style.color="green";
            }   

            body.appendChild(newt);//add the new element to the body
            idcount++;

        }
    }
    function gotVisits(visitItems)
    {
//assign the global variable to be 3
        type = 3;
    }

})();
```

This saves you from polluting the `window` object, which you should avoid doing anyhow and allows the inner functions access to the `type` variable.

It should do what you want.

Also the outer function wrapper for your `window.onload` is redundant, just do:

```
window.onload = onCreated;
```

Comment: Thanks Lloyd. I tried both of those method's and neither seem to make a difference. This seems very strange :/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `chrome.history.getVisits` executes the callback asynchronously, so you first try to check that variable, and it gets updated later. You can verify this with a pair of `console.log` messages.

Move the rest of the code inside the callback, so it gets executed at the right time.

Comment: I think that is probably true, but unfortunately I cannot move the rest of the code into the callback because the code needs to use the historyItems which cannot be accessed inside the callback. Hence I am having to use a global variable to pass "type" out of the call back for use in the gotHistory function.

Comment: Sorry, when you say "move the rest of the code inside the callback", do you mean put the code into the gotVisits function, or into the curly braces from where I call gotHistory?

Comment: put everything below `chrome.history.getVisits` into its callback function.

Comment: When I do that I get the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined" because historyItems is not defined inside that function...

Comment: sigh. `chrome.history.getVisits({'url':historyItems[count].url}, function(visitItems) { /* move the code here! */ });`